# Unable to run a push queue task on Google Appengine with the Python27 SDK

Tags: python, google-app-engine

When trying start a simple push queue task on Google Appengine Python27 SDK (which ran fine on Python 2.5) I'm now getting a traceback ending with:

```
File "c:\program files\google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\taskqueue\
   taskqueue_stub.py", line 1662, in ExecuteTask connection.putheader(header_key, header_value)

File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 924, in putheader str = '%s: %s' % (header, '\r\n\t'.join(values)) 

TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found
```

The TypeError above occurs for

```
header = 'Content-Length'

values = (112,)
```

That should obviously be values=('112',)

Thankful for any advice,

Mort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a bug and it has been reported: [Issue 6460: Development Server - taskqueue stub type error](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=6460)

To get it working you'll need to patch the SDK manually, file: **google/appengine/api /taskqueue/taskqueue_stub.py**, line which looks like:

```
headers.append(('Content-Length', len(task.body())))
```

fix to:

```
headers.append(('Content-Length', str(len(task.body()))))
```

Comment: Many thanks. That's got it working. I made the patch in two places:               line 239       line 1623